# kendo angular textbox conditionally display clear button

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

How can I conditionally display the clear button on the kendo angular textbox? Also, could someone give me a sample input for the clearButtonIcon property? I tried setting [clearButtonIcon]='k-i-x' and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [clearButton](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/api/TextBoxComponent/#toc-clearbutton) input property to conditionally display the clear button of the TextBox component. Please also check the following example demonstrating the **clearButtonIcon** property:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nfyrx1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

The list of Kendo Icons can be found at the following page:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/icons/icon/icon-list/

Simply copy a class from the example list and paste it as a string to the **ClearButtonIcon** property.